# How to package gwt application as a war file in maven?

Tags: gwt, package, maven-3

We are using `gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0`
`mvn compile` does work fine.
However `mvn package` does not work and ends up with a following error. The CLASSPATH does look right and contains all the classes of user and server part of gwt/2.4.0

.gwt.xml does look right too.

Not sure if this is the right life cycle phase we should be using to create the package that contains generated war file. ?
How do we generate the package in the first place, where gwt is involved ?

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile (default) @ xyz-alp-ui-web ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [com.xyz.solutions.alp.alpui]
[INFO] Compiling module com.xyz.solutions.alp.alpui
[INFO]    
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Z:/xyz-alp-ui-web/src/main/java/com/xyz/solutions/alp/client/ApplicationController.java'
[INFO]
[ERROR]  Internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/autobean/shared/AutoBeanFactory
```

I have `com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar`, `com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.4.0\gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar` in classpath.
We are using maven 3.0

Comment: You shouldn't have gwt-dev in your classpath for compile and packaging. Dev is only for dev mode execution.

Comment: Also, in your first statement, you state 2.0.4 but your program log shows 2.4.0 for the gwt-maven-plugin version. Is it 2.0 or 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

Place `gwt-servlet.jar` in your dependencies list.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

you can fiddle with **scope** setting changing it between *runtime* and *complile* to suit your needs. Oh and one more thing: remove `gwt-dev` from your *pom.xml*, as kabram stated above.